# Active Directory Authentication integration with solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

How to integrate Active Directory Authentication in solr?

I'm thinking is it be possible to use a custom plugin for **Active Directory Authentication** plugin in place of BasicAuthPlugin, any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: There is no Active Directory plugin bundled with Solr, but have you looked at the Kerberos authentication plugin? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Kerberos+Authentication+Plugin - I'd start by looking at the BasicAuthPlugin and implement AD authentication if you already know how to do that in Java.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. yes, I have implemented it in java.